# rails 3.0.12 how to check what version of activerecord do i have?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

Maybe it's a silly question but I need multiple primary keys in some tables something like...

```
create table t1
(
 id int not null
 id_something int not null
 .
 .
 .
 primary key (id, id_something)
)
```

I googled and I found this gem http://rubygems.org/gems/composite_primary_keys

but I couldn't find what activerecord version do I have

I'm using rails 3.0.12 and ruby 1.9.2p320

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Run `bundle show activerecord` at the terminal.

Comment: Works for rails 6

Answer (score 0):

Run `bundle info activerecord` in your terminal
As `bundle show activerecord`
is deprecated in some of the rails versions.